# complicated SQL: How to filtrate duplicate data about technical support and compute rank of order

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I’ve got a big problem. Could anyone give me a hand?

My first aim is:fliter the duplicate data with query statment( select not delete), that is, the various entries of EndTime and Qos for a same ServiceID due to the repeated feedback. The rule is to only keep the records with the lowest Qos for a same ServiceID. If there are several records having the lowest Qos, then only keep whatever one of these records. The client accepts and prefers to this scheme. In this example, for the ID=6,7, and 8, just keep 6 or 7.  I have got answer of this aim here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT serviceid,tcid,endtime,qos 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM service 
      ORDER BY serviceid, qos, id) AS base 
GROUP BY serviceid
```

aim2: Qos=1 represents the Satisfied Service. The monthly total Satisfied Services achieved by each technical support engineer is referred to as “Personal Total Satisfied Services this Month”. Those technical support engineers whose “Personal Total Satisfied Service this Month” ranking among the top 2 in that month are referred to as the “Top 2 since this Month”. If they are outstanding enough to be entitled to the “Top 2 since this Month” every month, then they can be referred to as “Outstanding of Class 1”. All in all, this step is to compute the “Outstanding of Class 1”. In this example, “Top 2 since this Month” for January is Andrew and Jacob, and that for February are Andrew, Dlyan, and Jacob. Therefore, the honor title of “Outstanding of Class 1” is awarded to Andrew and Jacob(just these 2 recorders).

please help me with aim2 (finally I should reach the aim 4, the final goal), result of aim 2 should be

```
TCID
Andrew
Jacob
```

explain:There are some technical service data (ServiceID, TCID, EndTime, and QoS) in a whole year, and ID is a unique primary key  because there are some duplicates.

Almost forget to say that, just a reminder, the client only accept the SQL instead of stored procedure in database to implement it. And I only need query statement because customer did not allow us to write database.

```
 some data:
```

```
ServiceID   ID  TCID    EndTime Qos
2000    2   Jacob   2011/1/1    2
2000    3   Jacob   2011/1/1    2
2001    4   Jacob   2011/1/1    2
2002    5   Jacob   2011/2/3    1
2003    6   Tyler   2011/1/4    1
```

Data Structure:

- ID: Unique primary key of record
- ServiceID: ID of a certain service
- TCID: ID of a technical support engineer
- EndTime: Ending Time of aservice
- Qos：Quality of service (1 Satisfied; 2 Average; 3Unsatisfactory/Dissatisfied).

DDL and insert SQL(mysql5):

```
CREATE TABLE `service` (
  `ServiceID` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL ,
  `TCID` VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
  `EndTime` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Qos` CHAR(1)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
);
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO `service` (`ServiceID`, `ID`, `TCID`, `EndTime`, `Qos`) VALUES
  (2004, 9, 'Jacob', '2011-02-04', '1'),
  (2000, 2, 'Jacob', '2011-01-01', '2'),
  (2000, 3, 'Jacob', '2011-01-01', '2'),
  (2001, 4, 'Jacob', '2011-01-01', '2'),
  (2002, 5, 'Jacob', '2011-02-03', '1'),
  (2003, 6, 'Tyler', '2011-01-04', '1'),
  (2003, 7, 'Tyler', '2011-01-04', '1'),
  (2003, 8, 'Tyler', '2011-01-03', '2'),
  (2005, 10, 'Jacob', '2011-02-05', '1'),
  (2006, 11, 'Jacob', '2011-02-04', '2'),
  (2007, 12, 'Jacob', '2011-01-08', '1'),
  (2008, 13, 'Tyler', '2011-02-06', '1'),
  (2009, 14, 'Dylan', '2011-02-08', '1'),
  (2010, 15, 'Dylan', '2011-02-09', '1'),
  (2014, 16, 'Andrew', '2011-01-01', '1'),
  (2013, 17, 'Andrew', '2011-01-01', '1'),
  (2012, 18, 'Andrew', '2011-02-19', '1'),
  (2011, 19, 'Andrew', '2011-02-02', '1'),
  (2015, 20, 'Andrew', '2011-02-01', '1'),
  (2016, 21, 'Andrew', '2011-01-19', '1'),
  (2017, 22, 'Jacob', '2011-01-01', '1'),
  (2018, 23, 'Dylan', '2011-02-03', '1'),
  (2019, 24, 'Dylan', '2011-01-09', '1'),
  (2020, 25, 'Dylan', '2011-01-01', '1'),
  (2021, 26, 'Andrew', '2011-01-03', '1'),
  (2021, 27, 'Dylan', '2011-01-11', '1'),
  (2022, 28, 'Jacob', '2011-01-09', '1'),
  (2023, 29, 'Tyler', '2011-01-19', '1'),
  (2024, 30, 'Andrew', '2011-02-01', '1'),
  (2025, 31, 'Dylan', '2011-02-03', '1'),
  (2026, 32, 'Jacob', '2011-02-04', '1'),
  (2027, 33, 'Tyler', '2011-02-09', '1'),
  (2028, 34, 'Daniel', '2011-01-06', '1'),
  (2029, 35, 'Daniel', '2011-02-01', '1');
 COMMIT;
```

this is my first 2 aims, there are 2 more, I am intended to complete all these steps one after another. Could anyone help achieve the first goal? I know it is quite complicated and many thanks to you in advance.

aim 3:Then, to compute the “Outstanding of Class 2” (the engineers of “Top 2 since this Month” are not included) equals to compute those ranking the third and the forth places. In this example, the “Outstanding of Class 2” is the Tyler.

aim 4:The final goal is to combine the “Outstanding of Class 1” with “Outstanding of Class 2”. The result will be ultimately transferred to report for rendering. My dataSet should like below:

```
TCID       level
Andrew     top2
Jacob      top2
Tyler      top4
```

result of goal 1 should like this:

```
2000   2   Jacob   2011/1/1    2
2001    4   Jacob   2011/1/1    2
2002    5   Jacob   2011/2/3    1
2003    6   Tyler   2011/1/4    1
2004    9   Jacob   2011/2/4    1
2005    10  Jacob   2011/2/5    1
2006    11  Jacob   2011/2/4    2
2007    12  Jacob   2011/1/8    1
2008    13  Tyler   2011/2/6    1
2009    14  Dyla    2011/2/8    1
2010    15  Dyla    2011/2/9    1
2011    19  Andrew  2011/2/2    1
2012    18  Andrew  2011/2/19   1
2013    17  Andrew  2011/1/1    1
2014    16  Andrew  2011/1/1    1
2015    20  Andrew  2011/2/1    1
2016    21  Andrew  2011/1/19   1
2017    22  Jacob   2011/1/1    1
2018    23  Dyla    2011/2/3    1
2019    24  Dyla    2011/1/9    1
2020    25  Dyla    2011/1/1    1
2021    26  Andrew  2011/1/3    1
2022    28  Jacob   2011/1/9    1
2023    29  Tyler   2011/1/19   1
2024    30  Andrew  2011/2/1    1
2025    31  Dyla    2011/2/3    1
2026    32  Jacob   2011/2/4    1
2027    33  Tyler   2011/2/9    1
2028    34  Daniel  2011/1/6    1
2029    35  Daniel  2011/2/1    1
```

Comment: have modified some ambiguous words

Comment: add aim 2,3,4, but please start with aim1.

Comment: a nice people give me a SQLServer solution, but I still need a mysql solution. statement of sqlserver is: select * from ( select *, row_number() over (partition by [ServiceID] order by Qos)  RN
 from [Service]
) T
where RN = 1
 order by [ServiceID]

Comment: I solved it myself, check below about esProc solution. But I need another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find a solution that is using esProc to solve this problem. 
esProc is the only solution I found. 
Yes, It can return a resultSet object and invoked by report Tool ( I'm using Jasper).
But I still need a SQL solution. so, please told me If there are any SQL solution. Thanks for your reply.

[image: esProc solution]

Here are some information about this solution: http://www.esproc.com/tour/what-is-esproc.html

Or here is a SQL Server Solution(but not fit for mysql):http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/e11c754d-559e-4eb7-9682-e998ea3387d9

Hope this helps people that meet the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This query intends to select only one row per SERVICE_ID
It will include only the records with lowest QOs for the corresponding SERVICE_ID and even then it avoids multiple rows by selecting only one.
As you have mentioned "keep whatever one of these records", I have used rowid to select one record at random

You can run the select query for this condition to see if the records extracted are okay with you before running the delete command

```
DELETE FROM SERVICE S
 WHERE S.SERVICEID IN (SELECT DISTINCT S.SERVICEID
                         FROM SERVICE S
                        GROUP BY S.SERVICEID
                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
   AND S.QOS =
       (SELECT MIN(S1.QOS) FROM SERVICE S1 WHERE S1.SERVICEID = S.SERVICEID)
   AND ROWID =
       (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM SERVICE S1 WHERE S1.SERVICEID = S.SERVICEID)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: In case this aim uses above table structure, then you may edit the question, or else if it uses some entirely different scenario , you should start a new question

Comment: sorry, I have made some mistaken, that query statement I posted maybe run under sqlserver, but not under mysql5. I will delete my last comment and modify the question to make it clear. sorry for my mistaken

Comment: hi, Rohan, does it more clear in the question, I have modified some ambiguous words.

Comment: Yes, it does help. Initially I had thought that you needed to directly delete the duplicate records(as per the rules you mentioned). What about the next part of question? the aim that you mentioned

Comment: I need fliter the duplicate data with query statment( select not delete)

Comment: I had add aim 2,3,4 in the question above, because It is too long to write in the comment area here. plz check it and give me any suggestion. thank you.

Comment: actually, I need "Top 5 since this Month", "Top 20 since this Month","Top 100 since this Month" and combine them. but It need too many data to test the sql statement. So I have simplified the question and made few data. It's enough to use.

Comment: hi, Rohan, I have got the answer of aim 1:SELECT DISTINCT serviceid,tcid,endtime,qos FROM (SELECT * FROM service ORDER BY serviceid, qos, id) AS base GROUP BY serviceid-----------and can you help me with the next step, aim2 or 3,4

Comment: please give me some advice about it.